# what symbol is this?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

do you know what's the name of the symbol that appear in equation 3  at the numerator? it's not the product and doesn't look like it's pi. From the context it seems it's meaning is the number of elements but i am not sure

[image]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: That's an indicator function, it returns 1 if that condition is met, else it returns 0.

Comment: thanks,do you know how the latex code for it?

Comment: `\Bbb <letter>`, e.g. `\Bbb I` $\to \Bbb I$

Comment: As the others have said, it's a blackboard bold I, written $\mathbb{I}$, representing here an indication function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes this is written using $\mathbb{1}$ instead of $\Bbb{I}$. It is a function defined on a set as follows:

$$\mathbb{1}_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } x \in A \\ 0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

for a set $A$.

so in your case,

$$\mathbb{I}(y_t) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } y_t \le F_t^{-1}(p) \\ 0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but  i was wondering if that symbol has a proper name or i  have to say  "the sum of the indicator function calculated....." ?

Comment: I've only ever heard of it referred to as "the indicator of ..." or "the indicator function of ..." or as "the characteristic function of ...."

Comment: thanksl, i will use it in this way  then